Docker Traefik routing not working as excpected
i do need some help regarding Docker traefiks and nodeJS backend:
My Proxy settings with HTTPS and serving my frontend on port 5000 works fine. But for some reason i dont get my backend http routes working:
That is how backend config looks like:
services:
   backend:
      image: node:latest
      container_name: nodejs-backend
      command: node /usr/src/app/index.js
      volumes:
         - ./dist:/usr/src/app
         - ./img:/usr/src/app/img
      networks:
         - default
         - web
      labels:
         - traefik.enable=true
         - traefik.http.routers.backend.rule=Host(`backend.my-domain.de`) || (Host(`backend.my-domain.de`) && Path(`/registerNewPlayer`)) # some more routes
         - traefik.http.routers.backend.tls=true
         - traefik.http.routers.backend.tls.certresolver=lets-encrypt
         - traefik.http.services.backend.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
networks:
   web:
      external: true

If i start the backend like so, i can hit the /login route. But nothing more than that works.
So below are my routes:
module.exports = class HttpRoutesConfiguration {

    constructor(app) {

        const storage = multer.diskStorage({
            destination: (reg, file, cb) => {
            cb(null, 'img')    // for prod '/usr/src/app/img'
            },
            filename: (reg, file, cb) => {
                cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
            }
        })

        const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

        app.use("/img", express.static('/img'));     //serve static img files
       
        app.post('/registerNewPlayer', upload.single("avatarPicture"),  playerController.registerNewPlayer);
    
        app.post('/login', bodyParser.json(), playerController.loginUser);

        app.post('/addPlayer', upload.single("avatarPicture"), playerController.addPlayer);

        app.post('/deleteUser', bodyParser.json(), playerController.deleteUser);
    }
}

and for testing purpose my cors config allow origin : '*'. I just want that every route after backend.my-domain.de/... hits the corresponding backend.
Here no route is working
- Host(backend.my-domain.de) && PathPrefix(/registerNewPlayer)
Here /login works. /registerNewPLayer returns 500 internal server error
- Host(backend.my-domain.de)
/login works. /registerNewPLayer returns 500 internal server error
Host(backend.hmy-domain.de) && ( PathPrefix(/login) || PathPrefix(/registerNewPlayer) )
/login works
Host(backend.my-domain.de) && (PathPrefix(/login))
/login works ; /registerNewPlayer doesnt work
Host(backend.my-domain.de) || (Host(backend.my-domain.de) && Path(/registerNewPlayer))

Your Traefik router rule should be simple
 - traefik.http.routers.backend.rule=Host(`backend.my-domain.de`)

and not complicated
- traefik.http.routers.backend.rule=Host(`backend.my-domain.de`) || (Host(`backend.my-domain.de`) && Path(`/registerNewPlayer`)) # some more routes

as Host() match is the same and always true, so the Path()/PathPrefix() does not matter.
The HTTP status 500 error is probably from your application. Enable Traefik access log in JSON format (doc) to see the response from your target service (OriginStatus) and from Traefik to the browser/client (DownstreamStatus).
